# Azure webapp for containers,cant attach azure blob storage account to container

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-storage, azure-web-app-for-containers

i am running multi layered container app in azure using an app service call "web app for containers".

i have blob storage account where i want my data to be saved, 
and i am trying to attach it to my app container. 
i configured the "path mapping" for my container with the following parameters:

```
{ name : AppDataVol , mouth path: /var/appdata, type:azureBlob ,AccountName:"*****" ,share name:"test-container" }
```

and... it seems to be ignored data do not persist it doesn't reach my storage volume,
and on restart everything gone...
i don't know what i am doing wrong i have been at it for almost a week!

below is my docker-compose file, to make it simple i removed the other services
please help me :(

```
version: '3'
services:     
    app:
        container_name: best-app-ever
        image: 'someunknowenregistry.azurecr.io/test/goodapp:latest'
        restart: always
        build: .
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'        
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=production        
        volumes:             
            - AppDataVol:/appData

volumes:
 AppDataVol:
```

Comment: Any updates? What is the status of your problem now?

Comment: Do you really want to solve the problem?!

Answer (score 0):

As my answer explained in your previous problem, mount Azure Blob storage to your container would work for you. But you need to understand the [caution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage#link-storage-to-your-web-app-preview):

> Linking an existing directory in a web app to a storage account will
>   delete the directory contents. If you are migrating files for an
>   existing app, make a backup of your app and its content before you
>   begin.

It means if the directory of the **image** already has files, then the mount action will delete the existing files in it, not persist them. So mount the Blob Storage to the container, you should find the directory which is empty and will have files when the image comes into a container, then mount the blob storage to it.